# Matching Contents from One Array to Another And Returning the Filtered Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to check values from one array against another array, and return a filtered array of just the matches.

So, for instance, I can do this to do a boolean check to see if there are matches:

```
let targetArray = [{"_id" : "111", city: "Los Angeles"}, {"_id" : "222", city: "New York", }, {"_id" : "333", city: "Seattle"}]

let filterValues = ["111", "333"];

let matchCheck = filterValues.every(el => targetArray.some(({_id}) => el == _id))
console.log(matchCheck) // returns true in this case
```

This returns `true` because there are matches.

But how would I return an array of just the two marching objects from the original targetArray? In other words, an array that looks like this:

```
[{"_id" : "111", city: "Los Angeles"}, {"_id" : "333", city: "Seattle"}]
```

Comment: you want to match based on id's ?

Comment: Yes, that'd correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how would I return an array of just the two marching objects from the original targetArray?

By using `.filter` + `.some`:

```
targetArray.filter(({_id}) => filterValues.some(el => el === _id));
```

You can also use a `Set` instead of an array to avoid `.some`:

```
let filterValues = new Set(["111", "333"]);
targetArray.filter(({_id}) => filterValues.has(_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this.**

```js
let targetArray = [{"_id" : "111", city: "Los Angeles"}, {"_id" : "222", city: "New York", }, {"_id" : "333", city: "Seattle"}]

let filterValues = ["111", "333"];

let op = targetArray.filter(e => {
  return filterValues.includes(e._id)
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Set` as `this` argument of filter()

```js
let targetArray = [{"_id" : "111", city: "Los Angeles"}, {"_id" : "222", city: "New York", }, {"_id" : "333", city: "Seattle"}]

let filterValues = ["111", "333"];

let filtered = targetArray.filter(function({_id}){ return this.has(_id)}, new Set(filterValues))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Driving the using of a `Set` to the max, you could use a closure over the set and take the obejct, separate the value for cheking with the set and return the result of it.

```js
let targetArray = [{ _id: "111", city: "Los Angeles" }, { _id: "222", city: "New York" }, { _id: "333", city: "Seattle" }],
    filterValues = ["111", "333"],
    filtered = targetArray.filter(
        (s => o => s.has(o._id))
        (new Set(filterValues))
    );

console.log(filtered);
```